# Allow Input Quantity Based On Available Quantity in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I need help in my problem since i need to input only the quantity based on the available quantity on my rows? How can i only submit the button if this requirement is met? How can i check for this?
Here's the link [LINK CODES](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-fwh5vb?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
initGroup() {
    let rows = this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      ingredient_id: ['', Validators.required],
      qty_available: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      qty: ['', Validators.required]
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Min or Max Validators https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators or Custom Validators https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators ? You only in submit check if (this.fb.isValid){....}

Comment: @Eliseo. Can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: qty: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.min(1)]]

Comment: @Eliseo. I mean how can i make a validator that compares the available quantity from the quantity?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you :(. I add the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//when push the fbgroup, add a customValidator

rows.push(this.fb.group({
      ingredient_id: ['', Validators.required],
      qty_available: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      qty: ['', Validators.required]
    },{validator: this.customValidator('qty_available','qty')}
    ))

//the customValidator function can be in your app.component.ts
//It's work because the validator is "attached" to the FbGroup, not to the all form

customValidator(campo1:string,campo2:string) {
  return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const available = group.controls[campo1];
    const qty=group.controls[campo2]
    if(available.value<qty.value){  //if error return "something" 
      return {
        out: true //<--THIS
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eliseo. By the way how can you show error when qty is inputted more than available quantity? How can you do this error in row, For example <div class="col-form-label" *ngIf="!form.controls['password'].valid && form.controls['password']?.touched">Password is Required</div>

Comment: Can you check my codes here. I tried to type quantity that is above my ordered quantity and the "error" word doesn't show up? Thanks. Here's the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-muwbuu?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Joseph, is row.hasError(' **out** '). The string is referred to the "object" that return the validator. change the name of the variable (I mark with "THIS" in the code)

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot