# Angular5 Custom Validators for Reactive forms

Tags: angular

I am having problems making a custom validator for my Angular v5 app. Following the docs for just the basic password match example in the [Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) but it doesn't validate.

```
this.personalInfoForm = _fb.group({
  'name': [null,Validators.minLength(7)],
  'email': [null, CustomValidators.emailOrEmpty],
  'password':[null],
  'password_confirm': [null]
}, this.passwordMatch); 


//EDIT

passwordMatch(g: FormGroup) {
      return g.get('password').value === g.get('password_confirm').value ?  null : {'mismatch': true};

}
```

Also, how would I go to be able to use the function with dynamic input names?
so that I can use it for emails, etc.
Ex: match('inputToMatch');

**EDIT:** Added HTML

```
<form class="col-lg-12" [formGroup]="personalInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="updatePersonalSettings(personalInfoForm.value)">
<h4>Basic Information</h4>
<div class="form-group row ">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="name" 
      placeholder="{{currentUser.name}}" 
      formControlName="name"
      />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input 
      type="email" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="email" 
      placeholder="{{currentUser.email}}" 
      formControlName="email"
      value=" ">
  </div>
</div>
<h4>Password</h4>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input 
      type="password" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="password" 
      formControlName="password"
      placeholder="password">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="password_confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input 
      type="email" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="password_confirm"
      formControlName="password_confirm" 
      placeholder="password confirmation" >
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button [disabled]="!personalInfoForm.valid || !personalInfoForm.dirty" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

GOT IT WORKING: but how can I pass parameters so that I can use this same method for different input names.

```
  passwordMatch(control: AbstractControl) {
    const password = control.root.get('password');
    const confirm = control.value;

  if (!password || !confirm) return null;
    return password.value === confirm ? null : { nomatch: true };
  }
```

Comment: Hi can you provide html source as well?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't validate (doesn't get fired)?

Comment: @HarryNinh well, because when I type two different password, I see the class ng-valid added. Also, the submit button becomes enabled. Meaning the personalInfoForm.valid = true

Comment: Hang on, your logic inside the validator is wrong. You are supposed to return non-null object only when the validation failed, not passed.

Comment: You're right! however, either way, the form still becomes valid, also, password_confirm must become required if password is dirty. Working on that change

Comment: Tried to return { misMatched : true }; to see if I can force an invalid but the field still shows valid.

Comment: you can use a customValidator like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071481/allow-input-quantity-based-on-available-quantity-in-reactive-forms/48074850#48074850 to pass arguments. see the flat arrow use

Answer (score 0):

I think I did what you want.  The code is prepared for PrimeNG, but mostly you just have to replace a few css classes to make it ready to bootstrap or other you need.

It's a component to validate required fields, minimum length, patterns and custom validations.
First, the examples about how to use:

**Example 1:  Validate: required, minlength and a pattern.**

some.component.html

```
<input pInputText type="text" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="user.email"
    ngModel #email="ngModel" required minlength="5"
    pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">

<app-input-validation [control]="email"
    [errDef]="{ required: 'A email is required',
    pattern:  'Enter a valid email address',
    minlength: 'The email should be at least 5 characteres'}" >
</app-input-validation>
```

**Example 2:  Validate: required, minlength and a custom function.**

some.component.html

```
<input pInputText type="text" name="name"  [(ngModel)]="user.name" 
    ngModel #name="ngModel" required minlength="5">

<app-input-validation [control]="name" [custom]="validateField1"
    [errDef]="{ required:  'A name is required',
    custom:    'Name must be diferent from sysadm',
    minlength: 'The name should be at least 5 characteres'}" >
</app-input-validation>
```

some.component.ts

```
...
// This validation funcion is called by the parâmeter [custom]="validateField1"
// and the component receive the field as argument. 
validateField1(context: NgModel ): boolean {
    if ( context.control.value === 'sysadm') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
...
```

Example 3:  Validate: required, minlength and a custom function envolving 2 fields.
some.component.html

```
...
<form #f="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="save(f)">
...
<div class="ui-md-6 ui-g-12 ui-fluid">
   <label>Password</label>
   <input pPassword type="password"  name="password"  
       [(ngModel)]="user.password" 
       ngModel #password="ngModel" required minlength="5" >
</div>
<div class="ui-md-6 ui-g-12 ui-fluid">
    <label>Retype Password</label>
    <input pPassword type="password"  name="repassword"
          [(ngModel)]="user.repassword" required minlength="5"  >
</div>

<!-- the parameter [form]="f" must be passed to app-input-validation 
    because the validatePassword must use 2 fields from the form -->

....
<app-input-validation [control]="password" [custom]="validatePassword"
    [form]="f" 
    [errDef]=
        "{  required: 'A password is required',
            custom:    'Both passwords must match.',
            minlength: 'The email should be at least 5 characteres'}" >
</app-input-validation>
</div>
```

some.component.ts

```
...
validatePassword(context: NgForm ): boolean {
if ( context.form.value.password === context.form.value.repassword ) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
...
```

If it fits your need, the code is:

**input-validation.component.ts**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-input-validation',
template: `
<div *ngIf="hasError()" class="ui-message ui-messages-error">
  {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
`,
styles: [`
.ui-messages-error {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
`]
})
export class InputValidationComponent {

@Input() control: NgModel;
@Input() form: NgForm;
@Input() errDef: any;

@Input() custom: any;

errorMessages = [];
errorMessage = '';

hasError(): boolean {
this.errorMessages = [];
this.errorMessage = '';
if ( this.errDef && ( this.control.errors || this.errDef['custom'] ) ) {
  Object.keys(this.errDef).some(key => {

    if ( this.control.errors && this.control.errors[key]) {
      this.errorMessages.push(this.errDef[key]);
    } else if ( key === 'custom' && !this.runCustom() ) {
      this.errorMessages.push(this.errDef[key]);
    }
    return false;
  });
}

for ( const m of this.errorMessages ){
  if ( this.errorMessage.length > 0 ) {
    this.errorMessage = this.errorMessage + '.  ';
  }
  this.errorMessage = this.errorMessage + m;
}

return this.errorMessages.length > 0  && this.control.dirty;

}
public runCustom(): boolean {
return this.custom(this);
}

}
```

And that's it.  I hope it helps. [https://gist.github.com/sannonaragao/dbf747676016ed0c4054f8abd2e2a4d2](http://Code%20on%20GitHubGist)